# Python 3 Debugging issue

Tags: python, debugging, python-idle

I have recently started to learn Python 3 and have run into an issue while trying to learn how to debug using IDLE. I have created a basic program following a tutorial, which then explains how to use the debugger. However, I keep running into an issue while stepping through the code, which the tutorial does not explain (I have followed the instructions perfectly) nor does hours of searching on the internet. Basically if I step while already inside a function, usually following print() the debugger steps into pyshell.py, specifically, PyShell.py:1285: write() if i step out of pyshell, the debugger will simple step back in as soon as I try to move on, if this is repeated the step, go, etc buttons will grey out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can try using better debugger [WingIDE](https://wingware.com/)

Comment: Have you tried stepping _over_?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, yeah I have tried stepping over. As soon as I try stepping again while inside a function it steps back into pyshell. Will try WingIDE now, cheers.

Comment: Are you using pdb?  Is so, it is acting correctly.  The problem is that Idle exec's user code using Python code, and not only C code, and pdb is designed to step into python code.  Idle has its own gui debugger that is aware of how Idle executes code.  It should not have the same problem.  I recently patched it so that breakpoints work much better.  The improvement will be in 3.4.2 and 2.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

pyshell.py file opens during the debugging process when the function that is under review is found in Python's library - for example print() or input(). If you want to bypass this file/process click Over and it will step over this review of the function in Python's library.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.4, I had the same problem. My tutorial is from *Invent with Python* by Al Sweigart, chapter 7.

New file editor windows such as `pyshell.py` and `random.py`open when built-in functions are called, such as `input()`, `print()`, `random.randint()`, etc. Then the `STEP` button starts stepping through the file it opened.

If you click `OVER`, you will have to click it several times, but if you click `OUT`, `pyshell.py` will close immediately and you'll be back in the original file you were trying to debug.

Also, I encountered problems confusing this one--the grayed-out buttons you mentioned--if I forgot to click in the shell and give input when the program asked. I tried *Wing IDE* and it didn't run the program correctly, although the program has no bugs. So I googled the problem, and there was no indication that `IDLE` is broken or useless.

Therefore, I kept trying till the `OUT` button in the `IDLE` debugger solved the problem.